# Pasar los datos de un formulario html a través de un script Perl

Tags: html, perl, cgi

Estoy comenzando a hacer scripts en Perl, pero me sale  un error:

Este es mi formulario en html. Ya vi los *name* de cada **input**; también vi la ruta  del **action**, que está bien. Y nada, sigue apareciendo un error...

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Mi FORMULARIO</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../estilos/estio.css">
</head>
<body>
 <form action="../cgi-bin/FORMULARIO.pl" method="post">
  <label for="nombre">Nombres: </label>
  <input  name="nombre" type="text" id="nombre" 
 placeholder="Escribe tu nombre">
  <label for="Email">Email</label>
  <input name="apellido" type="text" id="Email" placeholder="Escribe tus apellidos">
  <label for="mensaje" >Mensaje:</label>
  <textarea name="texto" type="text" id="mensaje" placeholder="Escribe tu mensaje"></textarea>
  <input type="submit" value="Enviar">
 </form>

</body>
</html>
```

Ahora voy a mostrar el script en Perl. Es básico...

```perl
#!usr/bin/perl -wT


use CGI;
use strict;

my $cgi=new CGI;

my $nombre    = $cgi ->param("nombre");
my $apellido  = $cgi ->param("apellido");
my $texto     = $cgi ->param("texto");

my $cabecera = $cgi->header(-type => "text/html");
   print $cabecera;
   print "<h1>Mucho gusto" .$nombre .$apellido."</h1>"."\n";
   print "<h1>Gracias por tu comentario</h1>";
   print "<a href='../html/MiFORM.html'>Regresar al formulario</a>";
```

Y el error que me sale es:

> Internal Server Error The server encountered an internal error or
>   misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.
>
> Please contact the server administrator at webmaster@localhost to
>   inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you
>   performed just before this error.
>
> More information about this error may be available in the server error
>   log.
>
> Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu) Server at 34.70.178.207 Port 80

¿Cuál es mi error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para comprobar la sintaxis de un programa Perl te vale con ejecutarlo con la opción "-c". En tu caso sería: `perl -cT FORMULARIO.pl`

El mensaje de error indica que es un problema de configuración del Apache, que quizás no tenga soporte para ejecutar CGI. O quizás, es que no encuentra el archivo FORMULARIO.pl.

Los cgi se suelen colocar en dos sitios: a nivel de sistema, en el directorio /usr/lib/cgi-bin/ y se referencian desde el formulario web como http://host/cgi-bin/FORMULARIO.pl (SIEMPRE poner una dirección absoluta en el **action**).

Otro sitio es en un directorio del usuario, que parece que es lo que es tu caso. Se trataría de un directorio cgi-bin/ dentro de tu directorio personal, pero dentro del directorio raíz de tu web.

En cualquiera de los dos casos, el Apache debe:
1) **estar** configurado para tener soporte de CGI. Una línea así en el cgi.load:

```
LoadModule cgi_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_cgi.so
```

2) indicarle **cómo** activar la ejecución de los cgi. Lo más sencillo es indicando la extensión del archivo. Una línea así en el apache2.conf o parecido:

````
AddHandler cgi-script .cgi .sh .pl .ida```
````

3) y decirle **dónde** se permite ejecutar los scripts cgi.

```
ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
<Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
    AllowOverride None
    Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Esto suele estar definido en el archivo `conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf` y sirve para definir el directorio virtual `/cgi-bin` en la web para que ejecute los *scripts* que están en `/usr/lib/cgi-bin/`

Para indicarle la ruta de los *scripts* de usuario, se lo definimos así:

```
<Directory "/home/*/cgi">
    AllowOverride Options
    Require all granted
    Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
</Directory>
```

Con esto decimos que los directorios cgi/ que estén dentro de las carpetas home// podrán contener *scripts* ejecutables.

Un tema importante: el programa debe tener permiso de lectura y ejecución, al menos para el usuario que ejecuta el servicio web, que suele ser httpd o apache2 o www-data.

Tienes mucha más información aquí: [cgi y configuración de Apache2](http://perlenespanol.com/foro/cgi-y-configuracion-de-apache2-t9138.html?hilit=cgi)